# Getting location working on SIM800L with TinyGSM?

Tags: esp32, library, gsm, sim800

Hey Arduino enthusiasts :)

I have purchased a **[LilyGo T-Call board](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800)**. Which has a Esp32 processor and a SIM800L GSM module. For my project i want to send location data over the 2G cellular network. I am using the **[TinyGSM library](https://stackoverflow.com)** for communicating with the GSM module, and it is working great so far. Communications with the modem, and sending SMS and cellular data is working correctly.

The challenge i am facing is retrieving the location data using the GSM network. In theory this should work fine. My module supports it as well as TinyGSM. But i just cannot seem to get a fix on the location. Running the example script `allFunctions` [link](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/blob/master/examples/AllFunctions/AllFunctions.ino) with only `gprs` and `GSM location` test running I get the attached at logs. I have naturally read the TinyGSM readme and followed their troubleshooting section.

In my research i found some relevant resources. **[This github issue](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/issues/378)** states the same problem, and with the exact same board. His problem however was about not getting SSL working which i do not need for my project. And from his AT logs you also see him getting a location after a little while. This **[SIM800L datasheet](https://www.avnet.com/wps/wcm/connect/onesite/5ddc2831-b698-44ac-92f5-50d79a14cb3f/Heracles-SIMCOM_GSM+Location_Application+Note_V1.02.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CVID=m31n15G&CVID=m31n15G&CVID=m31jwAj&CVID=m31jwAj)** documents the `CLBS` AT command. What i understood from it is that I am getting the `<locationcode> = 3` response which should be a `NET` error. But that does not really tell me much. There is also this **[TinyGSM gitter chat](https://gitter.im/tinygsm/Lobby#)** for the library.

I feel really lost here, so any help would be gladly appreciated :)

Comment: `cannot seem to get a fix` ... what does "seem to" mean? ... please describe the problem in detail, including a description of the data you expect and the data you actually get

Comment: You describe someone else's problem more than the problem you are facing, you provide nothing than "cannot seem to get a fix". TinyGSM behind the scene set the timeout for 2 minutes for querying GSM Location, and done twice (one for getting a String, another for getting a struct) in AlluFunction example, if all done right and you still don't get the location, you might want to check with your carrier whether the network support the feature or not. Not all the features that the module supported get supported by the carrier network, some need extra subscription fee.

Comment: BTW, GSM Location is Cell-based LBS, it does get a "fix" like GPS. It uses the cell-tower fingerprints that your module could "see" to querying a database to get back a lat,lng with accuracy of +/-500m.

Comment: thank you guys for comments. do you suggest i create a new more detailed post or should i edit this post?